# Android Relative layout "is not a sibling" error

Tags: android, android-layout, android-relativelayout

I have a 3 column layout like this:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" ... />
  <LinearLayout>
    <LinearLayout>
       <ImageView
          android:id="@+id/imageIcon" />
       ....
    </LinearLayout>
    <LinearLayout>
      ....
    </LinearLayout>
    <LinearLayout>
      ....
    </LinearLayout>
  </LinearLayout>
  <TextView 
     android:layout_toRightOf="@id/imageIcon" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

I am getting a "is not a sibling" error at the TextView part of the code.  The purpose of the TextView is to act like a "help" display. I'm trying to make sure that the TextView is always at the right side of that ImageView. Is there a better way in doing this?

Comment: hes out of a layout put him inside a layout

Comment: I somehow understand what's the cause of the problem.  I'm asking if there's a way to the desired effect.

Comment: so your textview shown after third column or imageIcon ?

Comment: just beside the 1st column above the 2nd column.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up using Custom Dialogs instead. I have to compute for the correct position of the dialog and set the values using this:

```
getWindow().getAttributes().y = mLocY;
getWindow().getAttributes().x = mLocX;
```

Answer (score 1):

`android:layout_toRightOf` is used to position elements in a relative layout, but your ImageView is inside of a LinearLayout.

You could give your LinearLayout an Id and position your text to the right of that.

Comment: If I use the 1st column's LinearLayout's id, I won't be able to use multiple "help" display on that particular column. If I use the LinearLayout id within the 1st column, the same error occurs.

Comment: You could wrap the ImageView in a horizontal LinearLayout, and add the TextView to that so it appears beside the image.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to align two views together, they must be within the same parent layout. As you will notice from your layout, the TextView is not inside the LinearLayout that your ImageView is in. I would suggest trying to align the TextView to the LinearLayout the ImageView is in.

Comment: If I do that.  The first column would get "fat".  I'm trying to do a help pop-up on items inside my first column.

Comment: then I would suggest you rethink your layout all together.

Comment: I'm currently exploring that option.  I was hoping there's a way to salvage the situation.

Comment: This is ridiculous. One of the key benefits of constraints is that they can position elements OUTSIDE of view hierarchy limitations.  **UGH** Android

Answer (score 0):

android:layout_toRightOf="@id/imageIcon" can be used when your view  are in the same parent layout but here your TextView is in LinearLayout, so if you want you can give android:layout_toRightOf to your LinearLayout.

Answer (score 0):

Somehow the android studio provides a solution that says that is not the best practice but you can set below code at build.gradle (app)

android {
    lintOptions{
        checkReleaseBuilds false
        abortOnError false
    }
.......///rest of code
}

I didn't have problems with the compilation until I asked Studio to make a signed apk. Then the problem occured...I overrided it with the above code